# Saving radio button options to access them later in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

This is my code for the radio buttons. I would like them to be displayed in the settings page and save it for future use.

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">  
<?php 
    wp_nonce_field('update-options'); 
    $rsp_position = get_option('rsp_position');
    if(empty($rsp_position)){
        $rsp_position = "true";
    } else {
        $rsp_position = get_option('rsp_position');
    }
?>  
<p><strong>Ad Placing:</strong><br />

<input type="radio" id="1" name="rsp_position" <?php if($rsp_position == 'true') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="true" />yes <br />
<input type="radio" id="2" name="rsp_position" <?php if($rsp_position == 'false') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="flase" />no <br />

<input type="text" name="publisher-id" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('publisher-id'); ?>" />  
</p>  
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save" /></p>  
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />  
<input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="publisher-id" /> 
<?php 
    settings_fields( 'save_position' ); 
    register_setting( 'save_position', 'rsp_position');
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using a `<form>`? In what context (which file) is this code happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going along the right lines, but your calls to settings_fields and register_setting aren't in the right place.

Read [Otto's tutorial on this](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/), it's a good introduction to the settings API.

Basically, add an admin_init action and in the callback register the setting and use add_settings_field to create the form items.

Then in your add_options_page callback you make the call to settings_fields to display the entries created with add_settings_field.

If you're still struggling having worked through Otto's tutorial, post back again.

**EDIT: Following pastebin entry.**

The failure to save is a result of your validation function not returning the expected value. The preg_match is not finding the right value and turning the string to '' (nothing) before saving - so it looks like it's not saving, when in fact it's saving nothing.

You could also check out the following functions which may be useful.

- [submit_button](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/submit_button)
- [settings_errors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/settings_errors)

Comment: This is my latest code: But this doesn't save the data! And I don't have an idea why! :( http://pastie.org/private/gmlhtnffjytwvr3m2zti3a Can you please help me!

Comment: You can clear up the 'Cannot modify header information' message by removing the white space in your opening/closing php tags. Never use a closing ?> tag at the bottom of a page and don't create gaps between ?> and <?php tags. If you're closing and opening again straightaway, don't even bother with them at all.

Comment: There is no error in fact. The data is simply not getting saved. Thats the issue! :(

Comment: You haven't returned your filtered value from the RSP_options_validate function. You need to return the value you want to save.

Comment: `return $options;` will do that right? I have done that already!

Comment: Do a var_dump( $options ); just before the return - does it have the value you expect? I suspect you'll find your preg_match is flawed - in teh test instead of setting the failed value to '' - set it to 'fail' (for example) and you'll see that as the saved value.

Comment: `array(1) { ["RSP_text_string"]=> string(0) "" }` This is what it gives me! I checked in the database too. It doesn't have the string I entered!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23236/discussion-between-mark-and-odx)